# Alternative way of writing If conditions

Tags: java, coding-style

I was wondering are there any alternative or elegant way of writing if conditions, if there

are more conditions that has to be checked.

Example,

```
if(cond1){
   if(cond2){
      if(cond3){
         if(cond4){
            //all conditions are checked
             flag = true;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use the logical AND operator.

```
if(cond1 && cond2 && cond3 && cond4) {
    flag = true;
}
```

It's equivalent in that if `cond1` is false, the rest of the conditions are not evaluated, and so on.

In this case, it may be even simpler to just directly assign the value (inspired by Patrick's original answer):

```
flag = cond1 && cond2 && cond3 && cond4;
```

Comment: I just wanted to add that it is `Short-Circuit Evaluation`. `false && anything` is short-circuit evaluated to `false` without evaluating `anything`. `true || anything` is short-circuit evaluated to `true`. Also only boolean operators (`&&` `||`) use this evaluation. Binary `&` or `|` are not using it.

Comment: @Pshemo Neither do boolean & and |. Your terminology is a bit confusing. It is the operator itself that is or isn't evaluated short-circuit: it has nothing to do with boolean or binary.

Comment: @EJP You are right. I forgot that when `&` and `|` are used on boolean variables then they are not called binary operators. It's hard to focus and write nice comment at 4.00 am :/

Answer (score 3):

A short readable, elegant way would be:

```
 flag = cond1 && cond2 && cond3 && cond4 ? true : false;
```

Or as pstanton says:

```
 boolean flag = cond1 && cond2 && cond3 && cond4;
```

Comment: you could even remove the brackets.

Comment: you could even remove the '? true : false;'

Answer (score 2):

If less is more, this is THE most elegant:

```
boolean flag = cond1 && cond2 && cond3 && cond4;
```

Answer (score 1):

As ZongLi indicates, it's easy to reduce this to a set of ANDs, but this gets more complex when you have complex logic

```
if(cond1){
   if(cond2){
      if(cond3){
         if(cond4){
            //all conditions are checked
             flag = true;
         }
      }
      if(cond4){
         flag3 = true;
      }
   }
   else
      flag2 = true;
}
```

Now you have a situation where reducing this isn't as simple

```
flag1 = cond1 && cond2 && cond3 && cond4
flag2 = cond1 && cond2 && cond4
flag2 = cond1 && !cond2
```

Reducing these to their boolean expressions, though, often makes things less readable and maintainable, because it loses the semantic relationship between the variables.  The example above might be rewritten as

```
if(cond1){
   if(cond2){
      if(cond4){
         flag3 = true;
         if(cond3){
             flag = true;
         }
      }
   }
   else
      flag2 = true;
}
```

or

```
if(cond1 && cond2){

      if(cond4){
         flag3 = true;
         if(cond3){
             flag = true;
         }
      }
}
else if(cond1){ flag2 = true; }
```

It's going to depend on the semantics of your code which is best, lots of nesting, though, suggests you might be better off using boolean expressions or restructuring your conditional tree.

It's useful to keep in mind boolean logical equivalences here, especially that `IF x THEN y` is logically equivalent to `!X or Y`